# Fisher-Yates shuffle Java implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, shuffle

This is my attempt at an implementation of the modern Fisher-Yates shuffle in Java. I'm not sure if it can be made more efficient, but I did my best to make it as simple as possible, and I learned how to use generics specifically for this, so If I did something wrong in that regard, let me know.

```
package com.kestrel.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class ShuffleTest
{
    public static <T> ArrayList<T> shuffle(ArrayList<T> a)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int n = a.size() - 1; n > 0; n--)
        {
            int index = rand.nextInt(n + 1);
            T temp = a.get(index);

            a.set(index, a.get(n));
            a.set(n, temp);
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static <T> T[] shuffle(T[] a)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int n = a.length - 1; n > 0; n--)
        {
            int index = rand.nextInt(n + 1);
            T temp = a[index];

            a[index] = a[n];
            a[n] = temp;
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

I know that I would have to implement methods for all of the primitive array types separately, but I'm short on time, and I don't think autoboxing will slow down my code all that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are both mutating & returning the value you are passing to the function.  Pick one.   Either return `void` or return a new array/`ArrayList` without mutating the input.

Your first `shuffle()` method requires an `ArrayList`, yet any `Collection` which implements the `List` interface would work, and will work well if it has \$O(1)\$ get & set complexity.  So consider loosening the type from a concrete type to the `List` interface.  (It will even work for `LinkedList`, albeit with horrible performance, but working slowly is arguably better than not being able to work at all.)

---

The value returned by `ArrayList<T>::set(int idx, T obj)` is the previous contents of that location.  Therefor, the temporary is not necessary.

```
        T temp = a.get(index);
        a.set(index, a.get(n));
        a.set(n, temp);
```

can become:

```
        a.set(n, a.set(index, a.get(n)));
```

or more clearly, just `Collections.swap(a, n, index);`.

Similarly,

```
        T temp = a[index];
        a[index] = a[n];
        a[n] = temp;
```

can also become `Collections.swap(a, n, index);`, a similar function which takes a `T[]` instead of a `List<?>` as the first argument.

---

Here is an implementation of your "*something like `K<T>` using generics*" from the comments.  And no longer coding from the hip, so the Java syntax is actually correct.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ aneufeld$ jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 10.0.1
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> public class ShuffleTest {
   ...>   public static <T,K extends List<T>> K shuffle(Collection<T> a, Supplier<K> supplier) {
   ...>     K dup = supplier.get();
   ...>     dup.addAll(a);
   ...>     Collections.shuffle(dup);  // Or use your shuffle implementation
   ...>     return dup;
   ...>   }
   ...> }
|  created class ShuffleTest

jshell> var orig = List.of("Hello", "world");
orig ==> [Hello, world]

jshell> ArrayList<String> shuffled = ShuffleTest.shuffle(orig, ArrayList<String>::new);
shuffled ==> [world, Hello]

jshell>
```

Comment: If I change ArrayList to List would there be any downsides?Also, I had thought I was only passing by value/returning. how to I tell whether or not something will get mutated or just have its value passed?

Comment: Due to “Type Erasure”, if you change `ArrayList` to `List`, and you pass in an `ArrayList`, you will notice zero difference in behaviour or performance, because exactly the same bytecode will being generated.  There shouldn’t be any downside.

Comment: Java is strictly pass-by-value.  However, what is being passed by value is a **reference** to the object (in this case, `List` or `ArrayList`). If you change the object in anyway, everyone with a reference to the object will see the change.  If you mutate the `a` object, the caller will see their list has changed.  If you set the variable `a` to a different value, such as `null`, the caller won’t see that change because the reference was passed by value.

Comment: if I change `public static <T> ArrayList<T> shuffle(ArrayList<T> a)` to `public static <T> List<T> shuffle(List<T> a)` it no longer lets me return into an ArrayList. Am I just doing It wrong? should I be using something like wildcards?

Comment: I’d not return anything. `public static <T> void shuffle(List<T> a)`.  Because the list is being mutated, you don’t need a return value to assign to anything.

Comment: In this case however, I'd like to be able to keep the original copy intact if necessary, and I figured returning a value is the cleanest way of doing that.

Comment: In that case, perhaps `public static <T> ArrayList<T> shuffle(Collection<T> c)`.  The first thing the function should do would be `ArrayList<T> dup = new ArrayList<T>(c);`, and then it would be free to sort this duplicate list.  You could pass in an `ArrayList<>`, but you could also pass in a `Vector<>`. Even a `LinkedList<>` would now shuffle in \$O(n)\$ time.  Unordered collections like `HashSet<>` could even be shuffled.  The catch is: it would always return an `ArrayList<>`.

Comment: so is it possible to do something like K<T> with generics?

Comment: Like: `public static <T, K extends List<? extends T>>  K shuffle(K a) { ... }`?   Sure.  But now you need to use reflection to create your duplicate `K`.   Better, you could pass in a `Supplier<K>` to create the object that will be returned.  Coding from the hip ... something like ... `public static <T, K extends List<? extends T>> K shuffle(K a, Supplier<K> supplier) { K dup = supplier.get(); dup.addAll(a); ...do_the_shuffle... ; return dup; }`.  You would call it with ... `ArrayList<String> shuffled_dup = ShuffleTest::shuffle(orig, ArrayList<String>::new);`

Comment: wow... that got really complicated really quick. so if I'm understanding you correctly, a supplier is used to tell the function what type of collection to use? I didn't even know the double colon operator was a thing in java. would a high school computer science class teach this stuff? I think I might be approaching the limits of what I can do on my own.

Comment: Sorry.  First double colon was a typo; should be a single period.  The double colon of `ArrayList<String>::new` is correct.  It is a method reference, introduced in Java 8.

Comment: so, most of that works. however, function from the list class, (set, addAll) gets an error. `The method set(int, capture#4-of ? extends T) in the type List<capture#4-of ? extends T> is not applicable for the arguments (int, capture#3-of ? extends T)` my best guess is that it wont let me assume that those functions will be available in whatever I pass in later, but I'm not sure, and I have no way of knowing how to fix it.

Comment: I said I was coding from the hip.  See edit.